# Place two buttons one on top of the other in a span

Tags: html, css

How do I get two buttons to appear one above the other in a span? The buttons should both be the same size also. I've tried vertical-align:middle and display:inline-block but with no success. The end goal is to have one list on the left, two buttons in the middle, and one list on the right. The buttons in the middle will be "Add" and "Remove" and move items between the two lists. I found [this](http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html) link but it was updated in 2004 and seems like a very poor way to do it. I've been searching for awhile and I must not be looking for the right things, so some guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: can you add your current html and css?

Comment: Could you show us how far you got with the code?

Comment: @Galled not very. I got two buttons to show up next to a list, all left to right.

Comment: So, do you have `<ul>...</ul>` on the left, then a span with the buttons, and `<ul>...</ul>` on the right? May I ask why you want to use spans instead of divs?

Comment: @Jarno That is exactly what I have. I thought using a div would push it to the next line...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here two buttons are aligned one above the other.

First between two lists:
http://jsfiddle.net/xGXER/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Buttons in between</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul style="background: #afa; display: inline-block; width: 100px; vertical-align: top;">
        <li>First</li>
        <li>Second</li>
        <li>Third</li>
        <li>Fourth</li>
    </ul>

    <span style="display: inline-block; width: 70px; background: #6af; vertical-align: top;">
        <button style="width: 70px;">Add</button>
        <button style="width: 70px;">Remove</button>
    </span>

    <ul style="background: #afa; display: inline-block; width: 100px; text-align: right;  vertical-align: top;">
        <li>Ein</li>
        <li>Zwei</li>
        <li>Drei</li>
        <li>Vier</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

...and then between two spans:
http://jsfiddle.net/JtXj2/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Buttons in between spans</title>
</head>
<body>
    <span style="background: #f06; vertical-align: top;">Foo bar has left the building</span>
    <span style="display: inline-block; width: 70px; height: 52px; background: #06f;">
        <button style="width: 70px;">Add</button>
        <button style="width: 70px;">Remove</button>
    </span>
    <span  style="background: #0f0; vertical-align: top;">Bar hopping is what we do at Friday nights</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If this was your goal + if there are any other layout issues you want to adjust right away, please let me know.

Comment: That was my goal, essentially. Is there any way to align the buttons like that without explicitly setting the height of the span? I would like to know how to tell them to float vertically instead of horizontally...

Comment: I updated the answer: no heights and added `vertical-align: top` into lists. I also tested with 0-1 list items. Works well in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

```
span { display:block; }
span button { float: left; width:100px; height:100px; margin:10px; clear:left; }
span .clearingelement { clear:left; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems too simple, but - if the question actually is "How do I get two buttons to appear one above the other in a span?", then... I think this is your answer.

```
<span>
BUTTON 1<br />
BUTTON 2
</span>
```

**EDIT:**

Set the width of the list and float it:

```
<ul style="width:100px; float:left;">
    <li>list item 1</li>
    <li>list item 2</li>
</ul>

<span>button1<br />button2</span>
```

Comment: When you put this next to a list, it causes one button to float below the list.

Answer (score 0):

The `span` element is an inline display element. Why not use a `div` element which is a block element?  I don't see the point of styling a `span` to act like a `div`

Comment: If I use a div the list has to be put inside the div also since the div is on its own line. The two buttons should be positioned inbetween two lists, and one above the other.

Answer (score 0):

Have you has only two buttons inside a `<SPAN>`? I guess the `<SPAN>` are inside a `<P>`, so I hope this would be what you need:

http://jsfiddle.net/Gpt6a/